# Rotate Digits problem - Why taking n mod 10 and n /10?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem on a leet code called Rotate digits.

This is the working solution of the problem in Javascript :

```
  var IsGood = function(n){
    let result = false;
   
    while(n > 0){
         let digit = n % 10;  // 2 % 10
         // ignore 0, 1, 8; by themselves, no change
        if( (digit === 3) || (digit === 4) || (digit === 7) ) return false;
        if( (digit === 2) || (digit === 5) || (digit === 6) || (digit === 9) ) result = true;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

var rotatedDigits = function(N) {
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 1; i <= N; i++){
        if(IsGood(i)) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

My question inside the IsGood function why are we taking n % 10 and then dividing n /=10. I have seen this implementation in almost all solutions to this problem. Can someone please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Step through the code, either with a debugger or, better IMO, with pen and paper to see how the numbers change with each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Take the number 123

The remainder of that number when divided by 10 is 3 (123 % 10) = 3.

So n%10 is giving you the last digit of the number

If you want to test the next digit in the number you have to remove the 3. The way to do that is to divide by 10 and only take the integer part (12.3 lose the .3 part) which you get by 123 / 10

You can keep doing that until you get to a number less than 10  which must be the final digit! this algorithm is a way to examine each digit in a number using math rather than string manipulation

```
123 % 10 = 3 first digit
123 / 10 = 12
12 % 10 = 2 next digit
12 /  10 = 1
```

1 < 10 so final digit